# Secrets Rotation using AWS Lambda and the AWS SDK for Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

Currently I am working on a use case where we need to store the `private keys` and `public certs` in `AWS Secret Manager`. We need to `rotate` the keys as well. However I am not able to find any documentation where the `lambda` is created in `java` template. Is there any way where we can rotate the `secrets` using `java` in `lambda`? Or do you suggest any other alternatives for storage?

I could find the below documentation but its in `python`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/reference_available-rotation-templates.html

Comment: Does [this article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotate-secrets_customize.html) help? It looks like you can use the CLI to find the rotation function for a secret, then open it in Lambda to modify it. Alternatively, [this article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotate-secrets_turn-on-for-other.html) covers rotating secrets not covered by the first article; under step 3d, you can create a function, and then view the new lambda function used for rotation.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't think any of them are in java. Not sure whether this feature is supported in java or not in the first place

Answer (score 1):

You can find how to use **AWS SDK for Java V2 for Secrets Manager** here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/secretsmanager

You can use this API and other AWS Services APIs within a Lambda function. We have different examples here under use cases:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2

Look through that can you will find different use case examples that show you how to use a Service Java API within a Lambda function. For example, this is a good example:

[Creating an AWS Lambda function that detects images with Personal Protective Equipment](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases/creating_lambda_ppe)

This shows you HOW TO use AWS SDK for Java V2 within a Lambda function. Once you understand that -- you can use other AWS Java Apis within a Lambda function -- such as Secrets Manager.

If you have questions, add a comment below.